# Fallout 4 difficulty question

Tags: fallout-4

If I weaken a legendary enemy on normal, then right before I kill it switch to survival; will I get a better legend drop?

Comment: I've played through on normal and very hard and so far the "legendary" items are like 1% legendary and 99% pure trash. While this doesn't answer your exact question - I wonder if the idea is that you keep seeing trash as well and wonder if there's actually any real legendary items in the game. Best I found was an explosive combat shotgun. Killed thousands of legendary foes though.

Answer (score 6):

**No.**

I haven't confirmed this through testing, but it's my understanding that enemy drops are determined at the time that the enemy is spawned. Therefore, changing your difficulty after the enemy spawns shouldn't affect the drops.

This [article on farming legendary drops](https://www.reddit.com/r/fo4/comments/3t08jh/farming_spots_for_legendary_enemies/) indicates that the drops are set once the dungeon spawns. This leads to the same conclusion.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean you could easily farm good items by raising the difficulty when the enemies spawn and reducing it again before you attack them?

Comment: @Philipp That might work.

Answer (score 0):

**No**

Loot is normally determined by a LeveledList which is a placeholder for items.
A LeveledList will be resolved on spawning an Actor/Container replacing the List with item calculated by Level, difficulty and a random factor.
Also a farming technique with spawning enemies in survival and kill in a lower difficulty will work one time without mods, as the engine limits to only one downscale from survival and then you stay below survival.